# Remove lowercase letters from a string in python

Tags: python

1. `str='www.wgoogle.cwm'`

   I need to remove all 'w' before and after .google. The expected output is .google.

   I tried `str.replace('w','')` which does not work. Is there better method than that?
2. Now, I need to remove all lowercase letters from the above string before and after .google.

   I tried the following without any success.

   ```
   word='www.google.com'

   print re.sub('[a-z]','',word)
   ```

   How could I do without writing a function?

Comment: Your code to remove all lowercase letters should work, and result in `..`. In the first case, I’m not sure why you want to end up with `.google.cm`. If that’s right, and you’re always going to have “google” as the middle part, well, there’s probably not a better method.

Comment: str.replace('w','') would replace all instances of w in `.google.` if it had a w. Ex: str = `www.wisthebestletter.com`, str.replace would give you `.isthebestletter.com` instead of `.wisthebestletter.com`

Comment: Then what do you mean by "without success"? What didn't work? Be specific.

Comment: @KevinL I would like to get .wisthebestletter.com. How can I do with str.replace?

Comment: @interjay - I did not post the question correctly. Please read it again. I need to remove all lower case before and after .google.

Comment: "str='www.wgoogle.cwm'. I need to remove all 'w' before and after .google. The expected output is .google." -- well, after removing all 'w' you would still left with 'c' and 'm'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are expecting ".google." then none of these options will work but this might:

```
word='www.wgoowglew.cowm'

print '.' + word.split('.')[1].replace('w', '') + '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, if you remove w's before and after .wgoogle. from string 'www.wgoogle.cwm' expected output should be '.wgoogle.cm'

```
str='www.wgoogle.cwm'
lst_str = str.split('.')
print(lst_str[0].replace('w','')+'.'+lst_str[1]+'.'+lst_str[2].replace('w',''))
```

My output is .wgoogle.cm

but if your are expecting .google. as your answer then use the following code

```
str='www.wgoogle.cwm'
print('.'+str.split('.')[1].replace('w','')+'.')
```

Output will be .google.